# Pandas flexible boolean row sub setting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, subset

Is it possible to subset a Pandas 1.3.4 dataframe by multiple row conditions for a single value?  To make this clearer, if I have a `df`:

```
index    col1    col2    
  0        A      10
  1        A      20
  2        B      130
  3        C      10
```

If I want to subset based on a `col2` value I can do `df[df['col2']>10]`:

```
index    col1    col2    
  
  1        A      20
  2        B      130
```

But is it possible to subset `col2` using different thresholds based on the `col1` value?

For example:

```
df[df['col2']>10 if col1 == 'A' 
   OR df['col2']>5 if col1 == 'C' 
   OR df['col2']>1000 if col1 == 'B']`
```

would give:

```
index    col1    col2    
  
  1        A      20
  
  3        C      10
```

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need compare for greater all values use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary and compare:

```
d = {'A' : 10,'C': 5 ,'B': 1000}

df[df['col2'] > df['col1'].map(d)]
```

Or if need different masks chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df[((df['col2']>10) & (df['col1']== 'A') ) |
   ((df['col2']>5) & (df['col1']== 'C') ) |
   ((df['col2']>1000) & (df['col1']== 'B') )]
```